# T-SQL what kind of constraint to use

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, constraints

I have the following two tables (only relevant key columns shown)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Jobs](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [JobNo] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Jobs] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Items](
    [JobID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BarcodeNo] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [SerialNo] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,

 CONSTRAINT [PK_Items_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [JobID] ASC,
    [BarcodeNo] ASC,
    [SerialNo] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I need to make sure that when an item is entered, the JobID matches an ID in the Jobs table. It seems, I can't use a FK because the PK in the items table is a composite key of 3 columns.

TIA

Mark
What kind of constraint can I use for this?

Comment: You can use a foreign key referencing more than one column.

Comment: Not in this situation because I don;t have the all 3 columns in the child table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A foreign key works fine.

There's no problem with having the single column `[dbo].[Items].[JobID]` reference the PK of jobs.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Jobs]
  (
     [ID]    [INT] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
     [JobNo] [NVARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Jobs] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [ID] ASC )
     WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
           STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
           IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
           ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
           ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
  )
ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Items]
  (
     [JobID]     [INT] NOT NULL REFERENCES [dbo].[Jobs]([ID]), /*<-- FK declaration*/
     [BarcodeNo] [NVARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
     [SerialNo]  [NVARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Items_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [JobID] ASC, [BarcodeNo] ASC, [SerialNo] ASC )
    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
          STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
          ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
  )
ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: I must be missing something then. I get an error saying there's no primary keyy in Jobs with JobID, BarcodeNo and SerialNo. From the searching I've done, most agree this can't be done. Only thing I could get to work was create a surrogate PK on Items, make JobID, BarcodeNo and SerialNo a unique index and then create the Fk between Items.JobID and Jobs.ID. Am i missing something?

Comment: @mark1234 Yes you must be. The code in my answer demonstrates that it works fine. If you are trying to add the FK after the table is created use `ALTER TABLE dbo.Items  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY(JobID) REFERENCES dbo.Jobs (ID)`

Comment: Don;t know what I was doing wrong. Works perfectly. Thanks a bunch

Comment: @mark1234 - From the error message you were getting sounds like you (or possibly a visual tool?) was executing `ALTER TABLE dbo.Items WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY(JobID,BarcodeNo,SerialNo) REFERENCES dbo.Jobs`

Comment: @"Martin Smith" - yes, that was exactly it. was using SSMS's visual tool.